# Does a max need to be set in android manifest?

Tags: android, firebase, android-manifest, ionic2

My ionic app is targeted 24, min 16, no max in android manifest.

When I run in firebase on devices set to 24 or 25 I get fatal crashes.

Does my app need a max to avoid crashes? Or does that limit it being supported on newer API devices?

Also in Android studio when you first try to set a project and pick a target it tells you that __% of people in the play store use that target so 24 is less than 1%. So if my target is 24 does that mean only 1% of the store will be able to use my app?

Here is my API 23 app crash on a 25 device:
[image]

API 24 app crash on a 24 device:
[image]

Comment: It's not customary (at least in my experience) to set a maximum sdk level. Perhaps you should investigate those crashes more and actually fix them rather than just avoiding them? Also, the usage percentage of those PI levels will increase as more users upgrade their devices or buy new ones, so it's really not useful to say "only 1% of devices have this API level" unless you are talking about older API levels that are becoming obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are a little bit confused, let's first clear what each of them means to Android.

### android:targetSdkVersion

With this you are telling Android which SDK you are targeting. What is important about this is that it tells the system that SDK level matchs this attribute, the system doesn't need to enable any behaviour to maintain compatibility.

Your app is still able to run on older versions (down to minSdkVersion).

### android:minSdkVersion

As the attribute name suggests this is the minium SDK version required in order to run the app, if the device which is trying to install the app has a lower sdk version the system will block the process.

What is important to note is that if you raise the minSdkVersion in an update, all the user which have already installed the app and no loger match this attribute will be able no longer to use the app

### android:maxSdkVersion

Again, the attribute name says it all. This is the maxium Sdk version a device can have in order to run the app.

Notice this from the docs:

> An application declaring maxSdkVersion="5" in its manifest is
> published on Google Play. A user whose device is running Android 1.6
> (API Level 4) downloads and installs the app. After a few weeks, the
> user receives an over-the-air system update to Android 2.0 (API Level
> 5). After the update is installed, the system checks the application's
> maxSdkVersion and successfully re-validates it. The application
> functions as normal. However, some time later, the device receives
> another system update, this time to Android 2.0.1 (API Level 6). After
> the update, the system can no longer re-validate the application
> because the system's own API Level (6) is now higher than the maximum
> supported by the application (5). The system prevents the application
> from being visible to the user, in effect removing it from the device.

That's it. [**Check also the DOCS here**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

---

> Also in Android studio when you first try to set a project and pick a
> target it tells you that __% of people in the play store use that
> target so 24 is less than 1%. So if my target is 24 does that mean
> only 1% of the store will be able to use my app?

Actually not, you have to consider the minium and max in order to find how many % of market will be able to use your app. That's just saying how many people (in %) have that SDK Version.

---

### About the crashes

I am quite sure that the problem is not related to the SDKVersion, maybe you should post some log in order to give a more detailed answer to that.

Hope it helped you :)

Comment: Thank you for explaining! I just posted my errors and crashes above, any help with that would be much appreciated since I am pretty stuck as to why this is happening.

Comment: @SaH it's a nullpointer you are trying to access a null object. Try debugging it :)

Comment: Thank you but tbh I don't know how to debug something in firebase test lab or with java. My app is ionic, it isn't referencing any of my ionic code so I'm at a loss debugging wise how to go about this. Also API 23 worked fine with an API 23 device so it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: My app's code is all html/css/js, no native java anywhere.

Comment: @SaH well actually without any code example it's difficult to know what is causing it

Comment: ok thanks, since I have no idea what is causing this since no java code I don't know what code snippet I could send. Do you do hybrid apps like ionic for android and have ever run into an issue like this? I use some cordova plugins but I highly doubt that is what is causing this.